# entity framework couldn't deletet edit and details

Tags: c#, razor

I build alittke website using c# razor.

I have a model class named "clientModel".

I used crud operation using entity framework.

at first, evrything worked fine .

But when I changed the primary key of the clientModel class from "tracingNumber" to "emailAdress" I can't delete and edit the db from the website.
when I try to do this I get HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

any idea??

controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VicoProject___NewVersion.Models;

namespace Project___NewVersion.Controllers
{
    public class ClientController : Controller
    {
        private ClientModelsDBContext db = new ClientModelsDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /Model/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Clients.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Model/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            ClientModels clientmodels = db.Clients.Find(id);
            if (clientmodels == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(clientmodels);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Model/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Model/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ClientModels clientmodels)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Clients.Add(clientmodels);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(clientmodels);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Model/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            ClientModels clientmodels = db.Clients.Find(id);
            if (clientmodels == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(clientmodels);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Model/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(ClientModels clientmodels)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(clientmodels).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(clientmodels);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Model/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            ClientModels clientmodels = db.Clients.Find(id);
            if (clientmodels == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(clientmodels);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Model/Delete/5



        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            ClientModels clientmodels = db.Clients.Find(id);
            db.Clients.Remove(clientmodels);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        public ActionResult Search(string search)
        {
            var r = db.Clients.Where(t => t.emailAdress.Contains(search) || t.name.Contains(search)).ToList();
            Console.Write(r);
          return RedirectToAction("Search");


        }
    }
}
```

client model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Project___NewVersion.Models
{
    public class ClientModels
    {

        [Required]
        public string name { get; set;}
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number must be 10 numbers") , MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Phone Number must be 10 numbers")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
        public String phoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string emailAdress { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientModelsDBContext : DbContext
    {
        static ClientModelsDBContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClientModelsDBContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<ClientModels> Clients { get; set; }
    }


}
```

the client/index view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.phoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emailAdress)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emailAdress)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.emailAdress }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.emailAdress }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.emailAdress})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: When I press on edit / details / delete on the index client view I get the HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Comment: your delete action require an id to find the entity, but you doesn't have a key of type int, instead your key it's a string; put a breakpoint to your action and inspect

Comment: I concluded that the problem is the "@". I pass email Adress and when I do this it's pass %40% instead of @. because of that db.find method doesn't find what I looking for. any idea??

Comment: dear user this is another question, first it was a 404, now is an encoding issue, in 2 completely different steps on your page pipeline...

Answer (score 0):

The function with the signature

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
```

needs to be called. The parameter to this is an int. I assume since changing it the id is now a string - so the framework doesn't know which method to call.

Comment: What does your http request look like?